# I uninstalled SharePoint server 2013 After that i can't remove site template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-template

I uninstall SharePoint 2013.

we have some package to install on web application it will be stored in 15 folder.
so after installation i try to install our package but it showing following error.

[image]

Actually i want to remove following template eContracts from Central Admin.

How i can remove this. I tried to uninstall the package then also this error came.

I tried Powershell script also (stsadm -o deletetemplate -title eContracts) but is not removing.

Please someone help for this how i can remove this site template ?

Thank in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally most of the folks deactivate and delete the Site Template though SP OOB from the Solution Gallery. Some time you cannot do that  ( don't know for the reasons:-).

You can remove the same by using Power shell. Below are the commands which are used to Deactivate and Remove the solution from the Gallery

**Deactivate the Solution:**

```
Uninstall-SPUserSolution -identity "Name Of the Solution.wsp" -Site "Path of the Site Collection"
```

or

```
Uninstall-SPSolution -identity "Name Of the Solution.wsp" -Site "Path of the Site Collection"
```

**Remove Solution:**

```
Remove-SPUserSolution -identity "Name Of the Solution.wsp" -Site "Path of the Site Collection"
```

or

```
Remove-SPSolution -identity "Name Of the Solution.wsp" -Site "Path of the Site Collection"
```

**Note:-**

The above two commands will prompts for Confirmation , click `Y` and action will be done.

Thanks.

Comment: I already tried this but this not working.
Error was came Cannot find an spsite object with Id or Url.

Comment: Check if the solution is available under **Site Settings** > **Solutions** in Central Admin?

Comment: No the solution gallery was empty.

Comment: this happens when you remove the wsp before disabling the feature!

you need to re-add the exact wsp's(correct version) disable them(feature) and then remove wsp in correct order(retract and then remove)!

Comment: OR Simply navigate to **Site Settings** and under **Galleries** find the **Site Template Gallery**.  You'll find the **Site Template** in there.  Delete it.

Comment: is the last solution worked for you?

Comment: Site Template Gallery this option is not there Under Site Settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39673/discussion-between-hardik-and-kavitha).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39730/discussion-between-hardik-and-kavitha).